# Vertically align multiple dropdown in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, vertical-alignment

**Problem:**

Vertically aligning multiple dropdown's in Bootstrap. Right now the left-hand side of the navbar is correctly aligned but not the right one. Appreciate any feedback how you should reason in order to solve this.

**Minimal Working Example (MWE):**

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Test</title>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- Loading Bootstrap -->
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Loading Fonts Awesome -->
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Bootstrap Languages -->
  <link href="https://webbutveckling-supervisor.c9users.io/sas/assets/css/languages.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Custom CSS -->
  <!--<link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">-->
  <!-- Favicon -->
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="asssets/images/favicon.ico">

  <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="assets/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/respond.min.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
  <style>
    html, body {
        height: 100%;
        min-height: 100%;
        background-color: #eae8db;
        padding-top: 30px;
    }

    /*===========  Positioning ============*/

    .container {
        width: 80%;
        min-height: 100%;
        padding: 0px 0px 75px 0px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    /*============  Navigation ============*/

    .navbar {
        height: 100%;
        background-color: blue;
    }
        .nav li {
            display:inline-block;
            float:none;
            margin:0;
            vertical-align:middle;
        }

        .navbar-nav {
            background-color: red;
        }

        .navbar-right {
            margin: 0;
        }

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar" role="navigation">
      <!-- Collect the nav links -->
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="/"><img src="http://placehold.it/450x100" alt=""></a></li>
          <li><a href="/">Boka resa</a></li>
          <li><a href="/">Erbjudanden</a></li>
          <li><a href="/">Resmål</a></li>
          <li><a href="/">Företag</a></li>
          <li><a href="/">Charter</a></li>
          <li><a href="/">Kundtjänst</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="dropdown" role="menu">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" title="Logga ut"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-lock"></i> Logga ut <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="/"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-paint-brush"></i> Test 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="/"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-shopping-cart"></i> Test 2</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown" role="menu">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" title="Språk"> <i class="lang-sm" lang="sv">&nbsp;</i> <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
              <li><span class="lang-sm lang-lbl-full" lang="sv"></span></li>
              <li><span class="lang-sm lang-lbl-full" lang="ar"></span></li>
              <li><span class="lang-sm lang-lbl-full" lang="be"></span></li>
              <li><span class="lang-sm lang-lbl-full" lang="bg"></span></li>
              <li><span class="lang-sm lang-lbl-full" lang="cs"></span></li>
              <li><span class="lang-sm lang-lbl-full" lang="da"></span></li>
              <li><span class="lang-sm lang-lbl-full" lang="de"></span></li>
              <li><span class="lang-sm lang-lbl-full" lang="el"></span></li>
              <li><span class="lang-sm lang-lbl-full" lang="en"></span></li>
              <li><span class="lang-sm lang-lbl-full" lang="es"></span></li>
              <li><span class="lang-sm lang-lbl-full" lang="et"></span></li>
              <li><span class="lang-sm lang-lbl-full" lang="fi"></span></li>
              <li><span class="lang-sm lang-lbl-full" lang="fr"></span></li>
              <li><span class="lang-sm lang-lbl-full" lang="ga"></span></li>
              <li><span class="lang-sm lang-lbl-full" lang="hr"></span></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="/"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-search"></i></a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <!-- / Navigation -->
  </div>

  <!-- jQuery (necessary for Flat UI's JavaScript plugins) -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.2.min.js" integrity="sha256-36cp2Co+/62rEAAYHLmRCPIych47CvdM+uTBJwSzWjI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
  <script src="https://webbutveckling-supervisor.c9users.io/sas/assets/js/flat-ui-pro.js"></script>
  <!-- JS for experiment -->
  <script src="https://webbutveckling-supervisor.c9users.io/sas/assets/js/application.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/58q66kr6/

**Output:**

[image]

**Desired output:**

Making the right-hand navigation vertically in the middle in order to align with the 450x100 placeholder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution for you is to create a new 'li' with visibility:hidden and with the same height of the first nav :

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Test</title>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- Loading Bootstrap -->
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Loading Fonts Awesome -->
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Bootstrap Languages -->
  <link href="https://webbutveckling-supervisor.c9users.io/sas/assets/css/languages.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Custom CSS -->
  <!--<link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">-->
  <!-- Favicon -->
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="asssets/images/favicon.ico">

  <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!--\[if lt IE 9\]>
    <script src="assets/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/respond.min.js"></script>
  <!\[endif\]-->
  <style>
    html, body {
        height: 100%;
        min-height: 100%;
        background-color: #eae8db;
        padding-top: 30px;
    }

    /*===========  Positioning ============*/

    .container {
        width: 80%;
        min-height: 100%;
        padding: 0px 0px 75px 0px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    /*============  Navigation ============*/

    .navbar {
        height: 100%;
        background-color: blue;
    }
        .nav li {
            display:inline-block;
            float:none;
            margin:0;
            vertical-align:middle;
        }

        .navbar-nav {
            background-color: red;
        }

        .navbar-right {
            margin: 0;
        }

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar" role="navigation">
      <!-- Collect the nav links -->
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="/"><img src="http://placehold.it/450x100" alt=""></a></li>
          <li><a href="/">Boka resa</a></li>
          <li><a href="/">Erbjudanden</a></li>
          <li><a href="/">Resmål</a></li>
          <li><a href="/">Företag</a></li>
          <li><a href="/">Charter</a></li>
          <li><a href="/">Kundtjänst</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li style="visibility:hidden;height:130px;width:0px;"></li>          
          <li class="dropdown" role="menu">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" title="Logga ut"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-lock"></i> Logga ut <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="/"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-paint-brush"></i> Test 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="/"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-shopping-cart"></i> Test 2</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown" role="menu">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" title="Språk"> <i class="lang-sm" lang="sv">&nbsp;</i> <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
              <li><span class="lang-sm lang-lbl-full" lang="sv"></span></li>
              <li><span class="lang-sm lang-lbl-full" lang="ar"></span></li>
              <li><span class="lang-sm lang-lbl-full" lang="be"></span></li>
              <li><span class="lang-sm lang-lbl-full" lang="bg"></span></li>
              <li><span class="lang-sm lang-lbl-full" lang="cs"></span></li>
              <li><span class="lang-sm lang-lbl-full" lang="da"></span></li>
              <li><span class="lang-sm lang-lbl-full" lang="de"></span></li>
              <li><span class="lang-sm lang-lbl-full" lang="el"></span></li>
              <li><span class="lang-sm lang-lbl-full" lang="en"></span></li>
              <li><span class="lang-sm lang-lbl-full" lang="es"></span></li>
              <li><span class="lang-sm lang-lbl-full" lang="et"></span></li>
              <li><span class="lang-sm lang-lbl-full" lang="fi"></span></li>
              <li><span class="lang-sm lang-lbl-full" lang="fr"></span></li>
              <li><span class="lang-sm lang-lbl-full" lang="ga"></span></li>
              <li><span class="lang-sm lang-lbl-full" lang="hr"></span></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="/"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-search"></i></a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <!-- / Navigation -->
  </div>

  <!-- jQuery (necessary for Flat UI's JavaScript plugins) -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.2.min.js" integrity="sha256-36cp2Co+/62rEAAYHLmRCPIych47CvdM+uTBJwSzWjI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
  <script src="https://webbutveckling-supervisor.c9users.io/sas/assets/js/flat-ui-pro.js"></script>
  <!-- JS for experiment -->
  <script src="https://webbutveckling-supervisor.c9users.io/sas/assets/js/application.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since you know the picture is `100px height` and the `padding` around is `10px`, you could apply a `margin-top: 40px;` to make it center vertically.

There must be a better way but it works like this.

[See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/58q66kr6/2/)

```
.navbar-right {
  margin: 40px 0 0;
}
```